# What does “24 hours prior” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My school asked me to “get a rapid antigen test 24 hours prior to the arrival time”. Does it mean that I need to get a test within the 24-hour timeframe leading to my arrival, or 24 hours before my arrival?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the literal meaning of the words is at odds with the implied context.

If you took the words at their exact meaning, you would obtain the test exactly 24 hours before arrival.

I assume that this is nonsense. For a start I think they want you to *take* the test, not just *get* it.

Secondly, they don't just want you to have tested.  They don't want you to test, and then arrive.  They only want you to arrive if you test negative!

And finally they don't actually care about the exact number of hours, provided it is recent. If you test 20 or 18 hours before arrival, and you are negative that is good too.  They probably wouldn't even mind much if you tested negative 25 hours before arrival.  But not 240 hours before!

Now those three things I know not from any knowledge of English, but from knowledge of how covid tests work, what they are for.  The school wants to know who will be coming so would like you test in advance, but not so far in advance that the test is worthless.

There is no "English learning" to be found here.  There is no special use of "prior", just slightly sloppy writing.

Comment: They really should require one the day before then another on the day. Having worked in an industry that tests everybody, every day, for the past 2½  years, even that's not enough. I tested negative on an LFT even though I had symptoms. I didn't test positive until the day after. [I didn't go to work either day, I've more sense than that ;))

Comment: @Tiara  I'd say even a negative swab four or five hours before the planned arrival is perfectly fine too. Perhaps the 24 hours is implying the cut-off time. If I am expected  to arrive at 9am on Monday, my test can be any time *after* 9am Sunday.  The instruction is unclear, if that's any comfort in knowing.